# How to resize without rotation with ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to resize images to 640x480 and fill the blank canvas space with black.  The following command works but it rotates the vertically taller images by 90 degrees.  I want to prevent any rotation.

```
convert source.jpg -resize 640x480 -size 640x480 xc:black \
    +swap -gravity center -composite destination.jpg
```

What do I have to do to prevent rotation?

Here's an example:

[image: Source]

[image: Destination]

Comment: Would you please post an example before and after showing the problem?

Comment: Seems to work fine with version `7.0.7-26`

Answer (score 0):

I find it more intuitive to use `-extent` to make a bigger canvas. See if this works for you:

```
convert image.jpg -resize 640x480 -background black -gravity center -extent 640x480 result.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Close but no cigar...  The original image is oriented correctly but size is now 480x640 rather than 640x480.

Comment: Have you maybe got an old IM version? It works fine for me. Else have a look here... http://imagemagick.org/Usage/photos/#orient

Comment: I IM from the website a couple of days ago.  It should be current.

Comment: Maybe try this to rule out EXIF.... `convert image.jpg -strip test.jpg` then resize `test.jpg`

Comment: When I run the `-strip` on the original image as in the above comment the resulting image gets rotated.  That's before I do a resize.  What does that mean?

Comment: I tried using `-auto-rotate -strip` together and that seemed to work correctly.

Comment: It tells us that there is something in the EXIF information causing the image to rotate, presumably the Orientation flag. You can look into it further with the `jhead` tool from here... http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/ I can't see it from here because images are stripped by SO when posting.

Comment: @PaulMatthews: this option is called `-auto-orient` in version `7.0.7-26`